# How to step over to only odd numbers in the nth diagonal of Pascal's -Sierpinski's triangle?

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

[image]

In this odd - even Pascal's triangle-Sierpinski's triangle, is it possible to step over to only odd numbers in the nth diagonal and never going checking every element in the diagonal to be even or odd?

NOTE: I understand with Lucas theorem, we can check if any location is odd or even, but that would need every position in the diagonal to be visited.

Comment: not sure how the Sierpinski-numbers tag fits in.

Comment: removed the tag.

Comment: do you see a pattern in the diagonals ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee not exactly. I can see that the first one has 0 differences, 2nd has 1 steppings, then 2 steppings, then 3,..... then 8. But after that I am confused.

Comment: what about the rows there's a pattern there for the all odd rows.

Comment: not sure about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65355/discussion-between-roddy-macphee-and-user3243499).